# Bounding the difference of frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times d$ matrices having real entries, and $0\leq ||A||^2_F-||B||^2_F\leq \lambda$, for some $\lambda \in R$. Let $L$ be a $j$-dimensional subspace (with $j<d$) of represented by an orthonormal matrix $[X]_{d\times j}$ (having columns orthonormal  to each other), then the problem is to give an upper and lower bound on the following expression
 $||AX||^2_F-||BX||^2_F$

In the above $||A||^2_F$ is the [frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) of $A.$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\|X\|_F^2 = Tr(X^T X)$.

Then we have $Tr(A^T A - B^T B) \leq \lambda$, and we wish to bound $Tr(X^T (A^T A - B^T B) X) = Tr( X X^T ( A^T A - B^T B))$. If the rows of $X$ are orthonormal to each other, then $X X^T = I$, so your expression is unchanged.

Comment: thanks for your response. In this problem columns of $X$ are orthonormal so $XX^T$ need not to be equal to $I.$